Expected time of activation waves in 1-dimension
Suppose we have $n$ sites, and assume each site activates at a rate $f_i$ ($1\leq i \leq n$), after which it triggers an activation wave that propagates in both direction at a rate $v$, activating neighboring sites, as shown

Once a site is activated (green), it remains so. Note that dormant (inactive) red sites can be passively activated from neighbouring activating waves. Notice also that it is not wave speed that is constant, but rather the rate at which each site is passively activated by a wave. Hence, we have the following random variables of interest:

$A_i\overset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim} \text{Exp}(f)$ := The time it takes for a site to self-activate;
$W_i\overset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim} \text{Exp}(v)$ := The time it takes for a site to be passively activated by a wave;
$F_{k}=\sum_{j=1}^{k} W_j \sim \text{Erlang}(k,v)$ := The time it takes for $k$ consecutive sites to be passively activated by a wave. Take $F_0=0$ for convenience.

Naturally, both of these times refer to the cases where the site has not yet been activated (either through self activation, or passively).
Question: For a given site $j$, what is the expected value of the time $T_j$ it takes for it to be activated, either by self activation, or by being passively activated by incoming wave?
Thoughts:

For simplicity, the problem can be considered over a ring (or an infinitely large domain).
This problem differs from a previously asked question, where $f_i=f, \forall i$, and where speed (not rate) was assumed to be constant. Here, we had $T=\min_i\{A_i+|i|/v\}$, for any site. While one could be tempted to define $T_j=\min_i\{A_i+F_{|i-j|}\}$, this is wrong, since waves could theoretically overlap, and we get extra conditionality.
The problem becomes harder since we will get conditionality on wave passage vs self activation. However, one should expect the expectation to be the similar as in the constant speed case, since $\mathbb{E}[F_{|i-j|}]=|i-j|/v$. In other words, I suspect that we have two different random variables with the same expectation. This is what I want to show
$$
\mathbb{E}[T_j]\simeq \mathbb{E}[\min_i\{A_i+\mathbb{E}[F_{|i-j|}]\}]=\mathbb{E}[\min_i\{A_i+|i-j|/v]\}].
$$
A geometrical argument could potentially be studied to derive an easy definition for $T_j$. For example, the following figures draw the potential "Erlang paths" in both cases (left is solved). Notice that, in the noisy case (where we consider $W_i$ for wave activation), one could iteratively remove origins that lay above any of the passively activating paths, but I wonder if there is an easier way to solve this. The darker line represents $\{T_j\}$.



This problem is reminiscent of crystal-growth in 1D. For example, in this work, the authors have used light-cone coordinates (from a Kolmogorov framework) to analyse a similar problem with space-time dependent wave speed (see discussion around page 70, and Eq 15). The difference here is that activation rates are defined over a continuum (with an activation rate set to $I(x,t)$), but, in theory,
$$
\mathbb{E}[T(x)]=\int_0^\infty s(x,t) \,dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-\int_{V_X[v]}I(Y)\,dY} \,dt,
$$
where $s(x,t)$ is the fraction of inactivated region at location $x$ and time $t$, $X\equiv (x,t)$, $Y\equiv (x',t')$, and $V_X[v]$ is the past light-cone. For the discrete case, could we somehow use Eq 23 in this work to answer this? That is, use
$$
I(x,t)=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta(x-i)f_i
$$
for our case, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta.


This has so much funky casework that I would probably just throw Monte Carlo at it. Each node has three possible states, say $I,W,A$ for "inactive, being wave-activated, active". A node in $I$ state, say $i$, self-activates at rate $f$; if this is the event, $i$ flips to $A$ and $i \pm 1$ flip to $W$ unless they were already $A$. A node in $W$ state activates at rate $v$; this event resolves the same way. A node in $A$ state does nothing.

(Cont.) Events in general occur at rate $R=\sum_i f 1_{S_i=I} + v 1_{S_i=W}$ in each transition, a given node in state $I$ activates with probability $f/R$ and a given node in state $W$ activates with probability $v/R$. Transitions themselves take Exp($R$) time (in the parameter=rate convention).

Oh, wait, how exactly does the wave propagation work in each case? Presumably the wave jumps over a node in $A$ state. What does it do if it hits a node that was already in $W$ state? Does that node become "extra active" or does it just consume the wave with no effect?

I understand, that is why I think the crystal growth framework could work a bit better, but I would still like to show that, on average, this problem is not dissimilar from the constant speed case.

No extra-activation, it just consumes it. Imagine a site $i$ is self-activated in time $A_i$ (say the first one to activate, i.e, the minimum of ${A_i}$). Then you generate the waves (Erlang paths) from $A_i$ to get the time points $A_i+\sum_{j=1}^{|k-i|}W_j$ for all the remaining sites $k\neq i$. Any point $p$ that satisfies $A_p>A_i+\sum_{j=1}^{|p-i|}W_j$ is excluded (this is what meant by lying in the "shadow of the light-cone"). Then you proceed to the next site that minimizes ${A_i}$, and so on. In the end, $T_j$ is given by the minimum at each site.

@Ian Ultimately, I suspect that $\mathbb{E}[T_j]\simeq \mathbb{E}[\min_i{A_i+\mathbb{E}[F_{|i-j|}]}]=\mathbb{E}[\min_i{A_i+|i-j|/v]}]$. In other words, the Erlang assumption does not alter the expectation. I might try to work out simple cases, like $n=1,2$. Perhaps there is an induction argument?

So you actually do have $T_i=\min_j A_j + F_{i,j}$ with $F_{i,j} \sim \text{Erlang}(|i-j|,v)$, and those are independent, because a node can be "processing" multiple waves at once even if it is already active? In that case you can just do $P(T_i \geq t)=P(\forall j \ A_j + F_{i,j} \geq t)=\prod_j \left ( \int_0^t f_{F_{i,j}}(s) P(A_j \geq t-s) ds \right )$. That integral can be done in terms of the incomplete Gamma function. If I'm wrong then I'm still missing something about the modeling.

My upper limit should be $\infty$, sorry.

No, actually what I think we have is two different random variables with the same expectation. This is what I want to show, but the formulation of $T_j$ can't be that one. To see this, consider again this case. Here, the true value of $T_j$ at the left-most side is not the minimum of all possible "time paths", because the wave start from the right-most point has passively activated the middle point, so any path generated from this point must be disregarded. Notice that this "overlapping" doesn't occur in the non-Erlang case, thus a minimum definition works there.

So basically each node can only ever generate a wave once, but an active node that is hit by a wave just absorbs the wave without effect? (Basically I am trying to understand how this "pruning" of the network based on "light cones" is self-consistent.) Also, the passive activations at $i+1$ and $i-1$ after $i$ self activates are independent, correct?

Yes, that is correct. So the "minimal" black curves you see in the plots in the question body are indeed the minimum in the non-Erlang case, but not quite the minimum in the Erlang case, because of the small example I showed. On average, however, I expect them to be the same. It is a technicality, but one that I would like to explain in a bit more detail. This is naturally a very special case because $\mathbb{E}[F_k]=k/v$. If the activation speed adopts any other space-time dependent behaviour, I think the problem is significantly harder. Have you looked into the light-cone framework?

Is it perhaps possible to work out the expectation of just the number of steps, without having to deal with the rates for the moment? The rates seem like they complicate matters to me, because there is this matter of the "number of nuclei" which affects the number of Exp($v$) clocks that are ticking at a time. (This is partially a question of: how different are $v$ and $f$?)

I see what you mean. In my application, however, they are significantly different. Intrinsic activation and passive activation should be understood as two, independent, clearly separate processes. Numerically, if you run the simulation on the right plot many times (even for space-dependent $f_i$), and average it, it essentially converges to the plot on the left. While this seems "intuitive" in a way, it's frustrating that I can't get an easy argument, without falling into complicated definitions of $T_j$. There must be an elegant definition that makes it clear that expectations are comparable.

But we could attempt something simpler first. Using the discretization suggested in point 5, for constant $f_i=f$, and constant speed $v$ (no Erlang distributions), can we deduce the formula you got in the other answer using the theoretical light-cone formula? They should in theory be equivalent. Even this seems tricky, because of discrete space. We need to let $n\to\infty$. Just some thoughts.

@Srini These are parameters of exponentially distributed random variables. See here.

@Srini Specifically, they are rate parameters of exponential random variables, so they have dimensions of frequency. There is a convention to parametrize exponential random variables by their mean instead, in which case the parameter has dimensions of time (but then you wouldn't call the parameter a rate).

Your analysis does not appear to take account of iterative activation
So far as I can see, there are parts of your analysis (both algebraic and graphical) that do not appear to take account of the possibility of iterative activation (i.e., when a site is activated by a neighbouring site and then activates a third site and so on).  Some of these are things you acknowledge in your description.  In particular, I think the approximating result you want to demonstrate here is not true in general, and will be a bad approximation when there are a large number of connected sites.  The approximation you say you want to get to (taking the variables $F_k$ to be used generically$^\dagger$) is:
$$\mathbb{E}[T_j]\simeq \mathbb{E}[\min_i\{A_i+\mathbb{E}[F_{|i-j|}]\}]
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\text{(Erroneous)}$$
The problem with this approximation ─as you note in point 2 of your description─ is that it appears to implicitly rely on the erroneous equation:
$$\quad \ T_j \simeq \min_i\{A_i+F_{|i-j|}\}
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \ \
\text{(Erroneous)}$$
This latter equation is false because it does not take account of the possibility of iterative activation over every possible path ─ it only looks at times generated either by the time-to-self-activation or activation one-step removed from this.  Similarly, your graph for the random rate case also seems to be incorrect by excluding iterative activation.  Since this would minimise over all possible pathways (rather than only the self-activation and one-step pathways) it would give a smaller value for $T_j$ and so it will tend to yield a smaller approximating value than what you have written in your desired approximating equation.
At best, your desired approximating equation might work okay if the connection of sites is such that iterative activation is unlikely to occur, or unlikely to substantially reduce the times-to-activation, which would rule out most processes of interest and largely defeat the point of examining this kind of complex process.  Because this is a complex process with a lot of dependencies, I cannot see any way that you are likely to get useful analytical results, even as an approximating equation.  It is likely that the best you can do here is to create an algorithm to simulate the process accurately and then estimate the relevant expected values from a large number of simulations of the process.  To this end, below I give a general algorithm for simulating the process.

Algorithm for the process: We will assume that the process is encapsulated by a distribution $f_A$ for the times-to-self activation, a distribution $f_W$ for the times-to-activation-of-neighbours and a binary $n \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{M}$ specifying the connections between sites (i.e., which sites can activate which other sites through a neighbouring relation).  Here is a general algorithm to generate the times-to-failure, allowing for iterative activation over every possible path.

Step 1: Set the initial times-to-activation for the sites as $t_1,...,t_n \sim \text{IID } f_A$ which are the times-to-self-activation.

Step 2: For $r = 1,...,n$ do the following:

Identify the site $k$ with the $r$th smallest time-to-activation (i.e., with $t_k = t_{(r)})$ and generate the times-to-activation propagated by that site to each other site, which we will call $w_1,...,w_n$.  (Generating these values will itself require iterative generation over the site path, which I omit for brevity.)

Update the times-to-activation for each site as $t_i := \min(t_i,t_k+w_i)$ (which now changes the ordered times-to-activation $t_{(1)},...,t_{(n)}$).




In the above algorithm we run through all the sites, starting from the one with first activation and proceeding to last activation.  At each step we update the time-to-activation by taking account of all pathways from the site under present consideration.  Activation through this site cannot occur earlier than activation of the site under consideration, which allows us to proceed through the sites only a single time.

$^\dagger$ For this analysis I am assuming that you are defining the $F_k$ variables "generically" since there would actually be a whole set of different times for different pathways of the same length (and these would be non-independent because they would include segments that share the same time between neighbouring sites).  This is a secondary source of error in these equations, but it is not the main error at issue here.

Note that I did state that what you call the "implicit reliance" on that definition is indeed wrong (see points 2 and 3 under 'Thoughts'). My claim is that we are describing two different random variables with potentially comparable expectations, but the random variables are not the same, and that definition is wrong for the reasons you and I mention. The general expectation is probably best approached with a nucleation-based framework (point 5). However, when considering Erlang-distributed RVs, I expect something more can be analytically said about the expectation of $T$.

The algorithm described is the clear definition of the random variable of interest. My question is then: where does the Erlang assumption simplify the problem (if at all). Numerically, if we average simulations in both cases of the left and right figures, the "minimal" path, or the black curve of interest, converge to the same path. This is what supports my claim, but I want to show it mathematically. So, on average, the definition could potentially be simplified. The Erlang, noisy paths will become straight lines, assuming independence of all processes, and the expectation parallelism emerges
